# When to apply a custom Android extension within a Gradle plugin?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I am trying to write a Gradle plugin which encapsulates common configuration settings for the `android { ... }` block in my projects. An example is adding a `dev` product flavor:

```
develop {
    applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    versionCode 100000
    versionName appVersionName + " (development)"
}
```

In the Gradle plugin I apply this configuration as follows:

```
class MyAndroidPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    private lateinit var myExtension: MyExtension

    override fun apply(project: Project) {

        myExtension = project.extensions.create(MyExtension.NAME, MyExtension::class.java)

        val androidExtension = extensions.findByName("android") as AppExtension
        androidExtension.productFlavors.create("dev") {
            with(project) {
                applicationIdSuffix = ".dev"
                versionCode = 100000
                versionName = "${myExtension.appVersionName} (development)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

... and my custom extension class

```
open class MyExtension {

    companion object {
        const val NAME = "myplugin"
    }

    var appVersionName: String? = "9.9.9"

}
```

When I configure my plugin in an Android project as follows ...

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.example.android.gradle"

android {
    ...
}

myplugin {
    appVersionName = "3.2.1"
}
```

... then the `versionName` is not modified - it is still "9.9.9". It seems the "3.2.1" value is not applied early enough. I tried `project.afterEvaluate { ... }` which results in the following error:

> Android tasks have already been created.
>   This happens when calling android.applicationVariants, android.libraryVariants or android.testVariants.
>   Once these methods are called, it is not possible to continue configuring the model.

Comment: I'm just guessing, try to change "versionName" naming, instead of `${myExtension.appVersionName}` => `${myExtension.versionName}`.

Comment: @mmmatey My bad. I fixed the variable name. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are facing is the following:

Imagine Gradle goes though your build script from top to bottom.
It finds your plugin and execute the `apply` function.
Inside that function you create the `productFlavor` and **apply** the values (`versionName` to `9.9.9` from your **extension**).
The `apply` method returns and Gradle goes further inside the build script.
It finds your extension setup, set the value to the extension and... continue “scanning” the build script.

And that its.

You need “something” (like an observer) which tells the AGP that the `versionName` of the `productFlavor` needs to be updated **as soon as the value of the extension is set**.

Gradle introduced some time ago the “Lazy configuration”. [See the docs here](https://docs.gradle.org/5.5.1/userguide/lazy_configuration.html).
With that it would be possible (in a Gradle way). But then the `ProductFlavor.versionName` should be of the type `Property<String>`. But that isn’t - state today.

Anyway. I found a "workaround" (I'm not sure if that is a workaround or acceptable in terms of how Gradle works):

You can put the `ProductFlavor` class as a constructor argument to your extension and update the values as soon as the extension property have set:

Your Plugin:

```
override fun apply(project: Project) {
    val androidExtension = project.extensions.findByName("android") as AppExtension
    val flavor = androidExtension.productFlavors.create("dev")

    val myExtension = project.extensions.create(MyExtension.NAME, MyExtension::class.java, flavor)
}
```

The extension:

```
open class MyExtension(
    private val productFlavor: ProductFlavor
) {

    companion object {
        const val NAME = "myplugin"
    }

    var versionName: String? = "9.9.9"
        set(value) {
            productFlavor.applicationIdSuffix = ".dev"
            productFlavor.dimension = "nuts"
            productFlavor.versionCode = 100000
            productFlavor.versionName = "$value (development)"
        }
}
```